# Getting the address of an rvalue

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, rvalue

```
class MyClass {
    public: MyClass(int a) : a(a) { }
    int a;
};

#include <iostream>
void print(MyClass* a) { std::cout << a->a << std::endl; }

int main() {
    print(&static_cast<MyClass&&>(MyClass(1337)));
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work with GCC 4.6, while it used to work in a previous version.

Now it says: taking address of xvalue (rvalue reference).

Is there any way to securely pass the address of an rvalue to another function?

Comment: `an rvalue reference (a.k.a. address of temporary)` one is not the same as the other

Comment: rvalue refernces : http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Comment: "What I want is to understand better the upcoming standard." And what understanding exactly are you going to get out of this, exactly? Maybe you should ask your actual question, the thing you actually want to learn, rather than this question about something you don't really want to do.

Comment: I attempted to condense the question to what I think is the essence of what you want to know. *However* that interpretation may have been quite liberal, so please review my edit (and rollback if you prefer). I'm afraid this might make the current answer look a bit disconnected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is: there is anyway to securely pass an rvalue reference (a.k.a. address of temporary) to another function without boringly storing it in a variable just to do that?

Yes, there is, like in the next example :

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
       public: MyClass(int a) : a(a) { }
       int a;
   };


void print(MyClass&& a) { std::cout << a.a << std::endl; }

int main() {
    print( MyClass(1337) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An rvalue does not necessarily have an address. However, there is a way to get the effect you want, by exploiting the fact that binding an rvalue to a reference forces it to be a temporary (which does have an address):

```
template<typename T> T *addressOfTemporary(T &&v) { return &v; }
```

Inside this function, `v` is an lvalue (despite being declared as `T&&`), so can have its address taken. You can use this function as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    public: MyClass(int a) : a(a) { }
    int a;
};

#include <iostream>
void print(MyClass* a) { std::cout << a->a << std::endl; }

int main() {
    print(addressOfTemporary(MyClass(1337)));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the temporary's lifetime ends at the end of the full-expression (the `print(...)` expression, in this case), so you will need to be careful that the pointer is not used past that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't particualrly need to print rvalues *only*, you can use a standard const reference instead:

```
class MyClass {
     public: MyClass(int a) : a(a) { }
     int a; 
};  

#include <iostream> 

void print(const MyClass& a) 
{ std::cout << a.a << std::endl; }  

int main() {
     print(MyClass(1337));
     return 0;
}
```