# std::apply may not be properly implemented

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

std::apply is mentioned in few stackoverflow answers and [n3658](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html), [n3915](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3915.pdf) and usually defined as:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, index_sequence<I...>) {
  return forward<F>(f)(get<I>(forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

template <typename F, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t) {
  using Indices = make_index_sequence<tuple_size<decay_t<Tuple>>::value>;
  return apply_impl(forward<F>(f), forward<Tuple>(t), Indices{});
}
```

However the reference implementation std::apply function fails to compile in such context (tested with clang 3.8 and gcc 5.2):

```
std::apply ([] (int&) {} , std::make_tuple (42));
```

One possible workaround is simply to remove std::forward<Tuple> from *apply_impl* but leave the universal reference intact:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, index_sequence<I...>) {
  return forward<F>(f)(get<I>(t)...);
}
```

Is there any drawbacks of this workaround? Is there more convenient solution possible?

**UPDATE**: Another possible workaround without changing *std::apply* (inspired by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834796/633160)):

```
template <typename T> constexpr T& make_tmp (T&& t) noexcept { return t; }
...
std::apply ([] (int& i) {} , make_tmp (std::make_tuple (42)));
```

Is it correct and result well defined?

Comment: It doesn't compile because it's ill-formed, you can't bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference.

Comment: That was the point of my question ;) You are right, it not possible to bind rvalue to lvalue ref. But semantically, I believe, the "apply ([] (int&) {} , make_tuple (42))" is pretty valid and the result should be defined. So the question was: should we change std::apply to let it to consume rvalue tuples?

Comment: `void f(int&); f(42);` is invalid. So why should your code sample be valid?

Comment: "Is there any drawbacks of this workaround?" Lots. You are forwarding rvalues as lvalues.

Comment: The problem is that your lambda needs to take either `int` or `const int &` - e.g. `std::apply ([] (int) {} , std::make_tuple (42));` should be fine.

Comment: @T.C. binding an rvalue to a reference forces it to be a temporary - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834796/633160

Comment: @Novelocrat I need to pass objects that is extremely expensive to copy. I can use functor instead of lambda, or lambda with 'auto' parameters, but I'm looking for more generalized solution first.

Comment: @NikkiChumakov "binding an rvalue to a reference forces it to be a temporary" -- that's true, but it needs to be bindable to begin with... e.g, lvalue-ref-to-non-const, rvalue-ref.

Comment: @NikkiChumakov it's not clear what you want to do within the lambda. are you just reading? `const T &`, do you need your own modifiable copy? `T`, do you know that it'll be a temporary? `T&&`. Also, if your object is expensive to copy, you should also make sure to use `forward_as_tuple` instead.

Comment: @mpark Please take a look at question update. Is it ok to write "std::apply (..., make_temp (rvalue))"?

Comment: @NikkiChumakov Your answer to T.C. is "how it could be made valid".  It does not address *why* your code should be valid.  `apply( f, std::tuple<...> )` is supposed to emulate calling `f` on the contents of the `tuple`.  If you call `f` on `42`, the code is not valid: the proper emulation of `apply( f, make_tuple(42) )` should then be ... code not valid.  Why should it be different?  Not "how can it be implemented to be different", but *why* should it work the way you want it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a temporary tuple containing a temporary object (or a reference to a temporary object), a function that demands a writable reference is right to reject the application.  The function expects callers to pay attention to what it writes, and you are deterministicly discarding it.

Here is code that compiles:

```
int main() {
  int i = 42;
  std::apply ([] (int&) {} , std::tie(i) );
}
```

`make_tuple` creates a tuple of *copies*.  `apply` then invokes the passed-in `f` on the soon to be discarded copies: these are quite properly treated as rvalues.

If you have an object which you want to pass by-reference through `std::apply`, put a reference to it in the tuple, not a copy of it.  Then the rvalue-ness of the tuple within `apply` does *not* apply to reference contents.

For `std::get<N>(some_tuple)` to return an rvalue, either:

(A) the nth element must be a copy, and the tuple must be an rvalue

(B) the nth element must be an rvalue reference, and the tuple must be an rvalue reference

By storing an lvalue reference, `std::get` will never return an rvalue reference.

You probably want to call `std::tie` or `std::forward_as_tuple` depending on the situation.  `std::make_tuple` is for when you want to create a copy in the tuple, not when you are storing references to other objects.

There are ways to allow you to pass rvalues as lvalues when you *do* want to discard any modifications, but those are usually bad ideas, and they should be done in client code with big warning stickers all over the place, not implicitly in a library.

```
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue( T&& t ) { return t; }
```

is a simple one.

Comment: You can use `std::ref/cref` with `make_tuple` if you want mixed copies/references. `make_tuple` unwraps them.

Comment: @T.C. *nod*, or `forward_as_tuple` if you are forwarding stuff into a tuple and want to keep a mixed bag of r and l values.